# Closing a window

Tags: javascript

This line is from my JSP file.

I opened this page by setting a target attribute in the `<a>` tag like `target ="_TOP"`, but the code below is not working.  How can I close this window?

```
<div><a href="JavaScript:window.close()">click</a></div>
```

Comment: the _top should be lowercase too

Comment: By the way, if you want to open a link in a new window, set the target to `_blank`.  `_top` will open the link in the same window but break out of any frames.

Answer (score 1):

You can only close a window with JavaScript that has been opened with JavaScript.  Since you went with an HTML method, this won't work.

However, if you were to re-code so that JavaScript was opening the window instead...

```
<a href="myurl" onclick="window.open('myurl'); return false;">mylink</a>
```

Then you could close the resulting window with JavaScript.

Comment: It should be noted that this is not the cleanest JavaScript to open this window - it can be done much less obtrusively.  This will work, though, and it's a lot more succinct.

Comment: can i close with any other method if i opened with HTML

Comment: None that I am aware of.  I figured JavaScript was an option to open the window since you wanted to close it with JavaScript too.

Comment: no it is not necessary to be closed using java script, is ther any other way to do that

Comment: Not that I know of.  I believe JavaScript is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

1. target should be _top - this will not pop a NEW window but overwrite the current - is that what you want
2. try this

   `<a href="page.jsp" target="_blank"

   onclick="var w=window.open(this.href,this.target); return w?false:true">pop a new window</a>`

or

```
<a href="page.jsp" target="mywin" 
onclick="var w=window.open(this.href,this.target); return w?false:true">pop a new window</a>
```

the later you can get the handle:

```
var w = window.open('','mywin');
if (!w.closed) w.close()
```